# For Loops Over Lists

Tags: python, function, loops, split, iteration

I am trying to read a file, remove the lines that begin with a "#" and then store the remaining lines in a list where I will try and split them into tuples.

The file "in.dat" is below

```
# read from file data about one day 
# format: start_time:end_time:#steps
09.30AM:09.45AM:220
11.45AM:12.23PM:300
11.45AM:10.23AM:302
2.45PM:3.23PM:202
3.45PM:3.53PM:90
5.45PM:5.53PM:80
6.45PM:7.23PM:1000
10.45PM:10.53PM:102
```

And the code is below

```
# Reads file and returns a list of lines in string format
def read_data(fname):
    with open("in.dat", "r") as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return data



# Takes a list of lines as input and returns a new list of lines with the 
# comment lines (the ones that begin with #) removed.
def remove_comment_lines(data):
    result = []
    for name in data:
        if len(name) <=30:
            result.append(data)
        print(result)
        return result
```

remove_comment_lines(read_data("in.dat"))

I have tried everything I can think of. I have no idea how to then take each of the times and find their times since midnight. But before I can do that I have to have the list with no comment lines AND be split with no "/n" characters.

Comment: Side note: you don't need to close the file when using a context handler. That happens automatically.

Comment: For one thing, you probably meant `result.append(name)`, not `result.append(data)`.

Comment: And you probably meant to do not put a return statement inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can read the file and put the data into a list (with converting the steps to integer):

```py
data = []
with open("in.dat", "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        # skip empty lines or lines beginning with #
        if line == "" or line.startswith("#"):
            continue
        data.append(line.split(":"))
        data[-1][-1] = int(data[-1][-1])

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
[
    ["09.30AM", "09.45AM", 220],
    ["11.45AM", "12.23PM", 300],
    ["11.45AM", "10.23AM", 302],
    ["2.45PM", "3.23PM", 202],
    ["3.45PM", "3.53PM", 90],
    ["5.45PM", "5.53PM", 80],
    ["6.45PM", "7.23PM", 1000],
    ["10.45PM", "10.53PM", 102],
]
```